# Wrong histogram from data

Tags: r, histogram

I have the data frame new1 with 20 columns of variables one of which is new1$year. This includes 25 years with the following count:

```
 > table(new1$year)
 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 
 2770 3171 3392 2955 2906 2801 2930 2985 3181 3059 2977 2884 3039 2428 2653 2522 2558 2370 2666 3046 3155 3047 2941 2591 1580
```

I tried to prepare an histogram of this with

```
 hist(new1$year, breaks=25)
```

but I obtain a histogram where the hight of the columns is actually different from the numbers in table(new1$year). FOr example the first column is >4000 in histo while it should be <2770; another example is that for 1995, where there should be a lower bar relatively to the other years around it this bar is also a little higher.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to define numeric(new1$year) (error says 'invalid length argument') but with no different result.
Many thanks
Marco

Comment: Maybe you want a `barplot`...

Comment: Thanks. Barplot results in a long black bar (or rectangle if you prefer) of no use.

Comment: You have to do `barplot(table(new1$year))`...

Comment: Smashing! Many thanks! Still do wonder why hist() did not work though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my comment, try:

```
barplot(table(new1$year))
```

The reason `hist` does not work exactly as you intend has to do with specification of the `breaks` argument. See [`?hist`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html):

> one of:
>
> a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
>
> a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
>
> a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
>
> a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells (see ‘Details’),
>
> a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> **In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only**.

Comment: So have tried different values for breaks (20,24,26, length(levels(factor(new1$year))),...) but the graphs that returns is the same.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier, the barplot(table(new1$year)) worked well. Just had tried specifying the breaks in the hist() (there are 25 years in the dataset so I put 25), but the hist is with columns of the wrong height (the first one being twice as tall as the others).

Comment: @MarcoD Yea, per the documentation, specifying a specific number will not guarantee appropriate breaks with your kind of data as it is only a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. That is very clear and also a little worrying (so maybe barplot(table()) is a better way to do it then! Will definitely keep that in mind in the future! Many thanks! Cheers

Comment: @MarcoD Great. Glad it was helpful. Just a note: I see you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions on Stack Overflow. It's good practice to accept answers (even if they are your own), so that others see your question has been resolved. You can accept an answer by selecting the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I did not know that, will do from now on! Cheers!